# How to deploy sveltekit application on non root path built using adapter-node?

Tags: node.js, assets, sveltekit, sveltekit-adapter-node, url-path

I have created a Sveltekit application which I want to host at non root path like http://localhost:3000/dashboard

My `svelte.config.js` is

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import preprocess from "svelte-preprocess";

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        paths: {
            base: '/dashboard',
        },
        csrf: { checkOrigin: false }
    },
    preprocess: [
        preprocess({
            scss: {
                prependData: '@use "src/variables.scss" as *;',
            },
        }),
    ],
    output: {
        globalObject: 'this',
    },
};

export default config;
```

I am using images like `<img src="/images/logo_new.svg">`

I am able to build using command

```bash
npm run build
```

To run I am using command

```bash
node build
```

Now I am able to see my application on `http://localhost:3000/dashboard` but images are not able to load. In console I am seeing 404 for all image paths.

My application is trying to open `http://localhost:3000/images/logo_new.svg` instead of `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/images/logo_new.svg`

What is right way to deploy sveltekit application on non root path?

Comment: Show how you set the `src` of the image.

Comment: I am using images like `<img src="/images/logo_new.svg">`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a base path defined you also have to use it when specifying things like an image `src` or link `href`:

```js
import { base } from '$app/paths';
```

```html
<img src="{base}/images/logo_new.svg">
```

An alternative would be to import the image which also has the advantage of an hash being added that will make sure the image is not cached too long.

```js
// whatever the path is from file, or put in sub-directory of `lib` and use `$lib/..`
import logoUrl from '../images/logo_new.svg';
```

```html
<img src={logoUrl} >
```

For generated assets the base should be added automatically.